# Istio Task - Testing Istio mutual TLS authentication - Can not perform on Bluemix for example BookInfo

Tags: ibm-cloud, istio, envoyproxy

Env: Bluemix + K8 + Istio + Bookinfo

Refer to https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/mutual-tls.html

When doing  - Testing the authentication setup , Step 4, it failed because the container has smallest linux installed which does not support curl command.

Comment: Also when I go into the container, I saw this : I have no name!@productpage-v1-3215019514-z6z67:/$ ls /etc/certs/
cert-chain.pem  key.pem  root-cert.pem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to get a shell to the container and install curl:

```
kubectl exec -it productpage-v1-XXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX -c productpage /bin/bash
apt-get update && apt-get install curl
```

Comment: Hi Vadim, Thanks for your reply. Actually I have tried that but failed because  of permission denied. Also sudo command is not avaiable as well

Comment: Hi Vadim, actually it resolved my issue.  the example command has the " -c istio-system" instead of "-c productpage" , you are right about that.  It's resolved after change that. Thanks a lot